# How do I get the unique set of values for a combination of dictionary keys?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, unique, python-3.7

I'm using Python 3.7.  I have a list of dictionaries, e.g.

```
my_dict = [{"a": 1, "b": 5, "c": 6}, {"a": 1, "b": 5, "c": 2}, {"a": 2, "b": 1, "c": 6}]
```

If I want to get the unique set of values for a single key, e.g. "a", I can do

```
set(d['a'] for d in my_dict)
```

but how would I get the unique set of values for the combination of keys, say "a" and "b"?  In the above example, the answer would be

```
[[1, 2], [1, 5]]
```

Comment: so you want for key `a` and key `b` : [ [unique values for a ], [unique values for b] ]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure about the requirements (unique with respect to what?), but in my interpretation the following works:

```
> {tuple(d[i] for i in ["a", "b"]) for d in my_dict}
{(1, 5), (2, 1)}
```

It also does the following:

```
> my_dict2 = [{"a": 1, "b": 5, "c": 6}, {"a": 5, "b": 1, "c": 2}, {"a": 2, "b": 1, "c": 6}]

> {tuple(d[i] for i in ["a", "b"]) for d in my_dict2}
{(1, 5), (2, 1), (5, 1)}
```

As opposed to

```
> [set(d[k] for d in my_dict2) for k in ["a", "b"]]
[{1, 2, 5}, {1, 5}]
```

Answer (score 7):

The same way; you just have to iterate over the keys as well.

```
[set(d[k] for d in my_dict) for k in ["a", "b"]]
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't really pay enough attention to the last line of your question.

Comment: Neither of these solutions give the output the OP asked for. They want the  set of **unique** pairs, not *all* pairs. So something like `set((d['a'], d['b']) for d in a)` will give the right result.

Comment: Hi, To confirm @ekhumoro said, I'm not getting unique results using the above.

Comment: From the OP, it seems this is closer to the correct answer.

Comment: @Dave what do you mean? May be your expectation is not clear. 
`[ set(d[key] for d in my_dict) for key in ["a", "b"] ]` => 
`[{1, 2}, {1, 5}]`. Does give the output as expected.

Comment: @Dave This produces the same result (after an update you may have missed) as you requested in your answer (up to the trivial difference of a list of tuples rather than a list of lists). If you need something else, you are going to have to update your question.

Answer (score 0):

The OP asks for something not completely specified, but illustrated with an example.
There are, so far, two answer posted.
None of them matches the requested example, so I am providing an alternative, which does match the example in the OP.

For the two cases used

```
my_dict = [{"a": 1, "b": 5, "c": 6}, {"a": 1, "b": 5, "c": 2}, {"a": 2, "b": 1, "c": 6}]   # In the OP
my_dict2 = [{"a": 1, "b": 5, "c": 6}, {"a": 5, "b": 1, "c": 2}, {"a": 2, "b": 1, "c": 6}]   # In one of the answers
```

the 2 options provided before, plus the current one, give

```
print([set(d[k] for d in my_dict) for k in ["a", "b"]])         # Answer #1
print({tuple(d[i] for i in ["a", "b"]) for d in my_dict})       # Answer #2
print([list(set(d[k] for d in my_dict)) for k in ["a", "b"]])   # Current Answer

print([set(d[k] for d in my_dict2) for k in ["a", "b"]])        # Answer #1
print({tuple(d[i] for i in ["a", "b"]) for d in my_dict2})      # Answer #2
print([list(set(d[k] for d in my_dict2)) for k in ["a", "b"]])  # Current Answer

[{1, 2}, {1, 5}]
{(1, 5), (2, 1)}
[[1, 2], [1, 5]]           <--- As requested
[{1, 2, 5}, {1, 5}]
{(1, 5), (5, 1), (2, 1)}
[[1, 2, 5], [1, 5]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the operator `itemgetter` to fetch multiple values from a dictionary:

```
from operator import itemgetter

zipped = zip(*map(itemgetter('a', 'b'), my_dict))
list(map(set, zipped))
# [{1, 2}, {1, 5}]
```